# How to measure distance between 2 GPS points in Pandas?

Tags: geoprocessing, geopandas, pandas, vincenty-formulae

I have two data frames both containing x,y GPS coordinates and I'm trying to determine if they are within a 1/4, 1/2 and 1 mile of each other. Like this:

```
# COORDS1
            DAY   LATITUDE  LONGITUDE
0        Friday  40.521504 -74.623842
1        Sunday  40.957955 -74.956354
2      Saturday  40.955194 -74.992973
3     Wednesday  40.983414 -74.783138
4        Friday  40.759895 -74.939406
5        Friday  40.632494 -74.896660
6      Thursday  40.786528 -74.738685
7       Tuesday  40.586635 -74.553266
8       Tuesday  40.596116 -74.690472
9       Tuesday  40.634075 -74.857825
10       Sunday  40.898246 -74.505033

# COORDS2
    LOCATION          LAT          LON
0        NaN  1000.000000  1000.000000
1  location1    40.999999   -74.999123
2  location2    40.555555   -74.666123
3  location3    40.777777   -74.777123


# Determine if coords2 are within a 1/4, 1/2 and 1 mile of coords1 :
            DAY   LATITUDE  LONGITUDE quart_mile half_mile   one_mile  five_mile
0     Wednesday  40.941523 -74.527043        NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN
1     Wednesday  40.936384 -74.575850        NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN
2       Tuesday  40.598387 -74.721645        NaN       NaN        NaN  location2
3        Monday  40.935171 -74.638239        NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN
4     Wednesday  40.931664 -74.896922        NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN
5       Tuesday  40.734261 -74.828369        NaN       NaN        NaN  location3
6       Tuesday  40.991758 -74.842690        NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Right now I'm estimating how many degrees lat/lon = 1/4 mile and then checking if the points are within <= to that distance. The problem is, a 1/4 mile is different for latitude than longitude so it's very inaccurate (incidentally it turns out to be an ellipse instead of a circle). How can I use vincenty or do point in polygon with 2 data frames to do this properly?

Here is my sample attempt that produces the above output.

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# DF1
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'DAY': np.random.choice(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'], 10000),
                    'LATITUDE': np.random.uniform(low=40.5, high=41, size=10000),
                    'LONGITUDE': np.random.uniform(low=-74.5, high=-75, size=10000)})
coords = df[['LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE']]
coords1 = coords.values[:, None].astype(float)


# DF2
data = [
    ['LOCATION', "LAT", "LON"],
    ['NaN', 1000, 1000],
    ['location1', 40.999999, -74.999123],
    ['location2', 40.555555, -74.666123],
    ['location3', 40.777777, -74.777123],
]
df_loc = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
coords = df_loc[['LAT', 'LON']]
coords2 = df_loc.values[None, :, 1:].astype(float)

#df_loc['lon_quart_mile_scalar'] = 1 / ((np.cos(np.radians(df_loc['LAT'])) * 69.172) / .25)
#df_loc['lat_quart_mile_scalar'] = (((np.abs(df_loc['LAT'] - 41)) * .00004139) + .00362289)
quart_mile_approx = .00362287
df['quart_mile'] = df_loc.LOCATION.iloc[(np.abs(coords1 - coords2) <= (quart_mile_approx)).all(2).argmax(1)].values
df['half_mile'] = df_loc.LOCATION.iloc[(np.abs(coords1 - coords2) <= (quart_mile_approx * 2)).all(2).argmax(1)].values
df['one_mile'] = df_loc.LOCATION.iloc[(np.abs(coords1 - coords2) <= (quart_mile_approx * 4)).all(2).argmax(1)].values
df['five_mile'] = df_loc.LOCATION.iloc[(np.abs(coords1 - coords2) <= (quart_mile_approx * 20)).all(2).argmax(1)].values

# How do I get this statement to work as a replacement for the above statements?
#df['TWO_MILE_TEST'] = df_loc.LOCATION.iloc[(vincenty(coords1, coords2).miles <= 2).all(2).argmax(1)].values

print(coords1)
print(coords2)

with pd.option_context('display.width', 1000, 'display.max_rows', 50):
    print(df)
```

How do I properly measure the distance between two sets of GPS coordinates using vincenty like the attempt below. Should I use df.apply?

```
df['TWO_MILE_TEST'] = df_loc.LOCATION.iloc[(vincenty(coords1, coords2).miles <= 2).all(2).argmax(1)].values
```

But it throws an error:

```
TypeError: __new__() takes from 1 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

geopy.distance.vincenty expects two parameters like this ((x,y), (x,y)).

Here are similar questions with useful snippets/attempts:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34621118/distance-calculation-in-geopy

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969282/how-to-use-geopy-vicenty-distance-over-dataframe-columns

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596213/grouped-by-dataframe-use-column-values-in-current-and-previous-row-in-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

- Cross join the two dataframes using `pd.merge`. (The `key` field is just an auxiliary to be able to compute a full cross join.)

  ```
  df_all = pd.merge(df.assign(key=0), df_loc.assign(key=0), on='key').drop('key', axis=1)
  ```
- Calculate the distance between each pair of points using `apply` with `vincenty`.

  ```
  df_all['MILES'] = df_all.apply(
      (lambda row: vincenty(
          (row['LATITUDE'], row['LONGITUDE']),
          (row['LAT'], row['LON'])
      ).miles),
      axis=1
  )
  ```

  This takes quite a while if you are to process more than a few thousand points; you might be interested in some less precise but faster methods of distance calculation such as the [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) - it is less precise, which probably does not matter if you are working on a mile scale, but is not iterative so can be computed using array calculations.
- For each point from the first dataframe, select only the closest point from the second dataframe.

  ```
  closest = df_all.loc[df_all.groupby(["DAY", 'LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE'])["MILES"].idxmin()]
  ```

  If you have a unique key for the points from the first dataframe, use it here as the `groupby` argument.
- Merge the location names and distances back to the first dataframe.

  ```
  df_withlocs = df.merge(
      closest,
      on=["DAY", 'LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE'],
      suffixes=('', '_cl')
  ).drop(['LAT', 'LON'], axis=1)
  ```
- Generate the label columns for the individual distance threshold. I did it like this:

  ```
  DISTANCES = [
      (.25, 'quart_mile'),
      (5, 'five_mile'),
  ]

  for dist, column in DISTANCES:
      locs = df_withlocs['LOCATION'].copy()
      locs[df_withlocs['MILES'] > dist] = np.nan
      df[column] = locs
  ```

  Just add the distance thresholds you need. `NaN` will appear where no location is in the desired range.

Comment: Thanks I verified it works, now need sometime to digest what's going on :)